# Muenchian grouping XSLT 1.0 multiple grouping

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I've read similar posts, but can't figure out how to apply Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0 based on multiple columns.

I'm stuck with the worst XML-file there is, can't change the layout. This is a sample:

```
<DataSet>
    <Row>
        <Cells>
            <Cell>COMPANY-A</Cell>
            <Cell>VG-ALG-TAX</Cell>
            <Cell>2021000009</Cell>
            <Cell>F29888</Cell>
        </Cells>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cells>
            <Cell>COMPANY-A</Cell>
            <Cell>VG-ALG-TAX</Cell>
            <Cell>2021000010</Cell>
            <Cell>F12350</Cell>
        </Cells>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cells>
            <Cell>COMPANY-A</Cell>
            <Cell>VG-ALG-TAX</Cell>
            <Cell>2021000010</Cell>
            <Cell>F12135</Cell>
        </Cells>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cells>
            <Cell>COMPANY-B</Cell>
            <Cell>VG-ALG-TAX</Cell>
            <Cell>2021000010</Cell>
            <Cell>F12350</Cell>
        </Cells>
    </Row>
</DataSet>
```

I want to use Muenchian grouping in XSLT1.0 to group by the first, second and third cell. The fourth cell needs to be linked to that key. Expected result:

```
<DataSet>
    <Invoice>
        <Key>
            <Company>COMPANY-A</Company>
            <Type>VG-ALG-TAX</Type>
            <Num>2021000009</Num>
        </Key>
        <Customers>
            <Customer>F29888</Customer>
        </Customers>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <Key>
            <Company>COMPANY-A</Company>
            <Type>VG-ALG-TAX</Type>
            <Num>2021000010</Num>
        </Key>
        <Customers>
            <Customer>F12350</Customer>
            <Customer>F12135</Customer>
        </Customers>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <Key>
            <Company>COMPANY-B</Company>
            <Type>VG-ALG-TAX</Type>
            <Num>2021000010</Num>
        </Key>
        <Customers>
            <Customer>F12350</Customer>
        </Customers>
    </Invoice>
</DataSet>
```

I've tried this, but there is no result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="document-by-number" match="GenericBrowseResponse/Select/Response/Selection/DataSet/Row" use="Cells/Cell[2]"></xsl:key>

<xsl:template match="GenericBrowseResponse/Select/Response/Selection/DataSet/Row">
    <Invoices>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Cells[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('document-by-number',Cells/Cell[2])[1])]"/>
    </Invoices>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cells">
    <Invoice>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('document-by-number', Cell[2])">
            <Document><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]"/></Document>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </Invoice>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *"I've tried this, but there is no result:"* That's not true. There is a result - just not the one you expect: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS8e That's because your stylesheet is nowhere close to what is needed here. It looks like you just copy/pasted some random code and hoped it would somehow work.

Comment: I't is indeed a lot of snippets combined from what I've found in similar questions. I can't figure out how to get on the right track. Can you @michael.hor257k give me some advice?

Comment: My advice is to abandon voodoo programming and study Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Here's a hint for ya: define your key as `<xsl:key name="k1" match="Cells" use="concat(Cell[1], '|', Cell[2], '|', Cell[3])" />`. That's the only complication here - the rest is standard Muenchian method.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank, the hint pointed me in the right direction. Still a bit of doubt whether this is the correct solution, but it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Tried some possibilities with the way the key is defined, Solved the issue with the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Cells" use="concat(Cell[1], '|', Cell[2], '|', Cell[3])" />
<!--<xsl:key name="k1" match="Cells" use="Cell[3]"></xsl:key>-->

<xsl:template match="/DataSet">
  <DataSet>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Row/Cells[generate-id()=generate-id(key('k1',concat(Cell[1], '|', Cell[2], '|', Cell[3]))[1])]"/>
  </DataSet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row/Cells">
    <Invoice>
      <Key>
        <Company><xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]"/></Company>
        <Type><xsl:value-of select="Cell[2]"/></Type>
        <Num><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]"/></Num>
      </Key>
      <Customer>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', concat(Cell[1], '|', Cell[2], '|', Cell[3]))">
            <Customers><xsl:value-of select="Cell[4]"/></Customers>
        </xsl:for-each> 
      </Customer>
    </Invoice>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```